# How to ref an map Id from outside component

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm creating a chat application that can filter messages by hashtags

The code in my main App is like as follows:

```
const App = ({ }) => {

const clickTag = (msgId) => {
// scroll to ref Id
// something like ref[msgId].current.scrollIntoView();
}

{ messages.map((chat, index) => {                                    
return (
<>
 <div className="box" key={chat.id}>
  <p className="ctext" id={chat.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: chat.body }}></p>
 </div>

<StyledSearchBar>
 <SearchBar clickTag={clickTag} />
</StyledSearchBar>
</>
}
```

And my outside component is the `<SearchBarComponent/>`

```
const SearchBar = ({clickTag}) => {
  
useEffect(() => {
    if (keywordSearch) {
      dispatch(searchTagMessages(keywordSearch));
    }
  }, [keywordSearch]);

 return(
   <div className="header">
     <div className="search-wrapper">
       <SearchInput
         name="seaching"
         className="search-input-wrapper"
         onChange={(e) => setKeywordSearch(e.target.value)}
         value={keywordSearch}
        />
     </div>
  </div>  
  <div className="sidebar-content">
    <div className="chatlist-container">
       <ul className="chatlist">
         { msgTags.map((msg, index) => {
           return (  
             <li className="chatlist p" key={msg.id} onClick={() => clickTag(msg.id)}>
               <p className="dialog-subtitle">                                  
                 <span className="user-message" id={msg.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: msg.body }}></span>
               </p>
             </li>
           )}
         </ul>
       )}
    </div>
  </div>
 )

}
```

So when a user clicks in a specific message in `SearchBar` component, the `messageId` callsback in the `clickTag()` function passed as props from `App` component.

Then in the `App` component `clickTag()` function should scroll to the message ref id received `msgId`.

But I didn't figure out how to create this ref's dynamically once the messageTags is received from an API.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getElementById` if you are in a  situation where you cannot pass a `ref` from `useRef`.  In your code, you could do it like so:

```
const clickTag = (msgId) => {
  // scroll to ref Id
  document.getElementById(msgId).scrollIntoView();
}
```

```
<li id = {msg.id} key={msg.id} className="chatlist p" onClick={() => clickTag(msg.id)}>
   <p className="dialog-subtitle">                                  
      <span className="user-message" id={msg.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: msg.body }}></span>
   </p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this feature without using `useRef`.

**1. Please add `id` in your chatlist element. It will be used to identify the element to be scrolled.**

```
<li id={`chatlist-${msg.id}`} className="chatlist p" key={msg.id} onClick={() => clickTag(msg.id)}>
```

**2. Implement the scrolling logic in your main component.**

```
const scrollToElement = (ele, offset) => {
  if (!ele) return;
  const rect = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo({
    top: rect.top + window.scrollY + (offset || 0),
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
};

const clickTag = (msgId) => {
    const ele = document.getElementById(`#chatlist-${msgId}`);
    scrollToElement(ele);
}
```

You can pass top offset in 2nd parameter in `scrollToElement` function.